# Как найти подходящие элементы в файле?

Tags: python

Есть файл `base.txt`, который содержит название элемента, межплоскостное расстояние `d` и интенсивность `I`:

```
element d I
Fe 2.0268 100
Fe 1.4332 19
Fe 1.1702 30
Fe 1.0134 9
Fe 0.9064 12
Fe 0.8275 6
Si 3.138 100
Si 1.92 60
Si 1.638 35
............
SiO2 1.279 3
SiO2 1.235 1
SiO2 1.203 1
SiO2 1.181 2
SiO2 1.095 3
```

Как сделать так, чтобы вывести элемент, который подходит введенным пользователем значениям `d` и `I`. При этом, значение `d` - приблизительно равное введенному значению.

Пример:

`Ввод значений`

```
d = 1.18
I = 2
```

`Вывод программы`

```
SiO2
```

Заранее всем спасибо

Comment: Загружаем файл в массив с помощью,например, pandas.read_csv Потом ищем подходящие значения

Comment: если с pandas `df.loc[df[df.I==2]['d'].sub(1.18).abs().idxmin()].element` Но можно и без pandas сделать: просто отсортировать по двойному ключу - равенство интенсивностей и абсолютной величине разности расстояний - и взять крайнее значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полный пример с `Pandas`, частично использована подсказка splash58. И я добавил элемент в данные с таким же `I`, чтобы проверить, что ищется именно ближайшее:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = """
element d I
Fe 2.0268 100
Fe 1.4332 19
Fe 1.1702 30
Fe 1.0134 9
Fe 0.9064 12
Fe 0.8275 6
Si 3.138 100
Si 1.92 60
Si 1.638 35
SiO2 1.279 3
SiO2 1.235 1
SiO2 1.203 1
SiO2 1.181 2
SiO3 1.191 2
SiO2 1.095 3"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

d = 1.18
I = 2
print(df.loc[(df.loc[df['I'] == I, 'd']-d).abs().idxmin(), 'element'])
# SiO2
```

Comment: * Добавлен элемент в выборку, чтобы проверить, что ищется именно ближайшее* - можно поподробнее. я не понял :(

Comment: @splash58 В данные добавлен, я не чётко выразился. "SiO3 1.191 2" - вот это я добавил с тем же I, чтобы проверить, что выберется не оно )

Comment: понятно. а то мне стало интересно, что я не знаю чего-то такого :))